# Email notification with Team Foundation 2005

Tags: tfs

I would like to get email notifications whenever a check in is done into Team Server. We have Team foundation server 2005. Is there a way to do that there? I know that the 2008 version has such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2005, on your `Team` menu (you need to connect to Team Explorer to get the `Team` menu), you should have a `Project Alerts...` item. This includes the option to be emailed whenever `Anything is checked in`.

*edit*

to check settings server side, look at your SMTP settings in the web.config in (somewhere like) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services . More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much ! I don't know how I didn't see that option before... But I'm not getting any emails... Could it be a problem in the server?

Comment: Yes, your server is probably not configured correctly.  The SMTP settings listed by AakashM are a good place to start looking.  If that doesn't help, run the "best practices analyzer" from the TFS Power Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install the Team Foundation Server Power Tools to edit alerts!

Best Regards